# Rxjava 2 - fetch data with realm and retrofit

Tags: android, kotlin, realm, rx-java2

Task: I want to fetch local data first. If returned data is null I want to call API service.

**Presenter**:

```
private fun getData() {
    val disposable = dataRepository.getDataFromRepository(String: itemId)
            .observeOn(AndroidSchedulers.mainThread())
            .subscribe({ _ ->
                // I got my data
            }, {
                // error
            })
    compositeDisposable.add(disposable)
}
```

**DataRepository**:

```
fun getDataFromRepository(itemId: String): Single<Data> {
    val dataAsSingle: Single<Event>

    //fetch data locally
    dataAsSingle = getDataLocally(itemId)

    //if nothing was found locally, call api service to fetch data
    if (dataAsSingle == null) {
        getDataFromApi(itemId)
    }

    return dataAsSingle
}

private fun getDataLocally(itemId: String): Single<Data> {
    var data: Data? = null

    val realm = Realm.getDefaultInstance()
        data = realm.where(Data::class.java).equalTo(itemId)
    // some other logic..
    realm.close()

    return data?.let {
        Single.just(data)
    } ?: Single.error(NoSuchEventFoundException())
}

private fun getDataFromApi(itemId: String): Single<Data> {
    return dataService.getDataFromApiCall(itemId)
            .onErrorResumeNext(ErrorHandler(BaseErrorParser()))
            .map { apiResponse ->
                    //some logic blah blah blah...
                    return@map data
                } 
            }
}
```

Well, I think my approach is wrong, but I can't initally tell you why... This works okay, but it seems that it skips main points of RxJava. Maybe someone can explain how to solve this problem with correct pattern and approach using RxJava 2?

**Updated**

**DataRepository**:

```
fun getDataFromRepository(itemId: String): Single<Data> {

    val localData: Observable<Data> = getDataLocally(itemId)
    val remoteData: Observable<Data> = getDataFromApi(itemId)
           .doOnNext(

            })

    return Observable
            .concat(localEvent, remoteEvent)
            .first()
}

private fun getDataLocally(itemId: String): Observable<Data> {
    var data: Data? = null

    val realm = Realm.getDefaultInstance()
        data = realm.where(Data::class.java).equalTo(itemId)
    // some other logic..
    realm.close()

    return Observable.just(data)
}

private fun getDataFromApi(itemId: String): Observable<Data> {
    return dataService.getDataFromApiCall(itemId)
            .map { apiResponse ->
                    //some logic blah blah blah...
                    return@map data
                } 
            }
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Actually, the proper way to do it with Realm would be to listen for changes in the Realm, and update the Realm from a background thread from the API if the Realm doesn't contain what you're looking for

(with limitation of using this method from UI thread, in order to receive RealmResults to UI thread - this way you can use async transaction and listen for changes in Realm):

```
private fun getData() {
    val disposable = dataRepository.getDataFromRepository(String: itemId)
            .observeOn(AndroidSchedulers.mainThread())
            .subscribe({ _ ->
                // I got my data
            }, {
                // error
            })
    compositeDisposable.add(disposable)
}
```

Where:

```
fun getDataFromRepository(itemId: String): Observable<Data> =
    Observable.create { emitter ->
        val realm = Realm.getDefaultInstance()
        val results = realm.where<Data>().equalTo("itemId", itemId).findAllAsync()
        val listener = RealmChangeListener { results ->
            if(!emitter.isDisposed()) {
                emitter.onNext(results)
            }
        }
        emitter.setDisposable(Disposable {
            results.removeChangeListener(listener)
            realm.close()
        })
        results.addChangeListener(listener)
    }.subscribeOn(AndroidSchedulers.mainThread())
    .doOnNext { results ->
        if(results.isEmpty()) {
            dataService.getDataFromApiCall(itemId)
                       // .toSingle() // ensure this completes automatically, but only if it's not a single already
                       .subscribeOn(Schedulers.io())
                       .subscribeWith(object: DisposableObserver<>() {
                           fun onNext(data: Data) {
                               Realm.getDefaultInstance().use { realm ->
                                  realm.executeTransaction { realm ->
                                      realm.insert(data)
                                   }
                               }
                           }

                           fun onError(throwable: Throwable) {
                               ... /* do something */ 
                           }
                      )
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Well, sync happens every X amount of time, so I don't think I should listen for Realm changes. Can u take that in account and edit the place with RxKotlin (not using it for learning purposes, please)? Nonetheless, this was informative.

Comment: Actually, if sync happens independently every X amount of time, then that's exactly why you should be listening for Realm changes! :D

Comment: In fact, if you have a separate `Observable.interval()` to start updates on the background thread, then you can use that to save into the Realm, instead of using `doOnNext`

Comment: Ohhh... I have difficulties when I try to `emitter.setDisposable {..}`. It says Type mismatch. Required: Disposable?, found: () -> Unit. Also, `.toSingle()` says `unresolved reference`.

Comment: ah , you are getting Single already, and you need to help out the SAM conversion a bit, i guess. Edited

Answer (score 0):

You can use `concat` operator. The important part is you should not return null value from your local source. You should return `Empty Observable` to get remote call. Here's an example code:

```
final Observable<Page> localResult = mSearchLocalDataSource.search(query);
final Observable<Page> remoteResult = mSearchRemoteDataSource.search(query)
                .doOnNext(new Action1<Page>() {
                    @Override
                    public void call(Page page) {
                        if (page != null) {
                            mSearchLocalDataSource.save(query, page);
                            mResultCache.put(query, page);
                        }
                    }
                });

        return Observable.concat(localResult, remoteResult)
                .first()
                .map(new Func1<Page, Page>() {
                    @Override
                    public Page call(Page page) {
                        if (page == null) {
                            throw new NoSuchElementException("No result found!");
                        }
                        return page;
                    }
});
```

Comment: I'm having difficulties grasping the idea and using you suggestions with my code sample. Can you please modify example for my case, please?

Comment: it's same as your code. just replace local and remote result with your implementation and use concat with your own local and remote implementations.

Comment: I updated code. I commented places where I'm confused.

Comment: first means if it can emit data in first observable you pass go on with it. if it cannot emit from second observable.

Comment: I see. Do you have any idea, why `remoteResult` and `localResult` concatination says, that I'm trying to return Single, not Observable? Could it be of realm?

Comment: I think so too, but then it says "No value passed for defaultItem attr"